# How do I make our iOS app appear as a bookmark in Facebook's new iOS app (released October)?

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile, bookmarks

We have an existing Facebook app (>1year) and now also an iOS app. How can I make our app appear in the bookmark section for those users who have our native app installed?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the Facebook Single-Sign-On for your app.

Comment: Thanks Vgho but I wonder is that really needed? In the new FB iOS app I see bookmarks to bejeweled blitz and doodle jump and for both I have never connected with facebook?

Comment: On second thought, no. All is needed is the URL scheme and the Facebook app ID to be added to the Info.plist file of your iOS project. Just like in the Single-Sign-On. You can read the instructions on the SSO tutorial